# Can a Dell OptiPlex 745 accommodate an SSD?

Tags: ssd

I have an older Dell OptiPlex 745, which has a 0RF705 motherboard, containing ATA drive controllers.

I went into BIOS and BIOS said there were SATA drives attached.

This PC has no PCIe slots, just PCI slots.

Can this PC accommodate an SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, no problem.

Lack of PCI-e port means, that you can't use SSD drive with PCI-e.

You need is SSD drive with SATA port.

Keep in mind that Dell 745 doesn't have latest very fast SATA-3 controller. If you use very fast SSD - it will work with reduced performance, but still much much better than HDD.

I would expect SATA-I or SATA-II there. SATA revisions are compatybile both ways (you can connect old disk to new controller or new disk to old controller).

SATA revisions (its from wikipedia: link)

> SATA revision 1.0 - 1.5 Gbit/s - 150 MB/s
>
> SATA revision 2.0 - 3 Gbit/s - 300 MB/s
>
> SATA revision 3.0 - 6 Gbit/s - 600 MB/s
>
> SATA revision 3.2 - 16 Gbit/s - 1969 MB/s

So, my suggestion would be: don't buy fastest SSD on the market, because you will be not able to use it's full speed on Dell 745.

Comment: I updated my answer (more info)

Comment: I downloaded [Crystaldiskinfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) and it says I have SATA 300, which must be SATA 2.